# How can I reproduce this beautiful table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I stumbled upon this TOC today:

[image: The sample TOC]

I really like its structure and simplicity. The page numbers are right behind the entries, and not unnecessarily remote as they often are. The separation between chapter numbering on the left and titles on the right clearly sets the two apart.

I would like to reproduce this design for a book, but have no idea where to start. Can you show me how to reproduce this?

**Bonus**
Do you have any idea how this could be extended to also list sections, and remove the authors?

Comment: I suppose you want it to be automatically generated, as opposed to typing it in?

Comment: Which document class do you use? Always nice if you add a minimal example.

Comment: I just want to remark that for most theses this structure is *too* simple. This is clearly the TOC of a book that is a collection of chapters by different authors so the requirements are different. But if you're sure that nobody would ever want to look up the page number of a particular section or even subsection then sure, go for it :)

Comment: I should have mentioned: do you think there is any way to add sections to this in a sensible way :-)?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> [image: pretty toc]

Use [etoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc).

The update enables sections in the TOC (see below for the first answer). Furthermore, it uses `\chaptername`, `\partname`  (available in the `book` class) for internationalization. And it uses a non-breakable space before the page number.

> [image: pretty toc with sections]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsetlevel{authors}{1}
\etocsetlevel{section}{2}
\etocsetlevel{subsection}{3}
\etocsettocdepth{section}
\newcommand{\authorstotoc}[1]{\etoctoccontentsline{authors}{#1}}

\newlength{\tocleft}
\setlength{\tocleft}{3cm}

\newlength{\tocsep}
\setlength{\tocsep}{2em}


\etocsetstyle{part}{}{}{{\bfseries\makebox[0pt][r]
                              {\partname\ \etocnumber\hspace{\tocsep}}%
                     \etocname\kern1em\relax\etocpage\par}\vspace{3ex}}{}

% to avoid possible line breaks between chapter (or part) name and page number
% replace \quad by \kern1em\relax

\etocsetstyle{chapter}{}{}{\etocifnumbered
                             {\makebox[0pt][r]
                               {\chaptername\ \etocnumber\hspace{\tocsep}}}
                             {\ifcase\TEMP
                              \def\TEMP{1}\or\def\TEMP{2}%
                              \makebox[0pt][r]
                                  {\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\tocleft-\tocsep\relax}
                                   {\raggedleft Introductory\\ \strut \chaptername}%
                                   \hspace{\tocsep}}\fi
                              }\textbf{\etocname\kern1em\relax\etocpage}\par
                             \etocifnumbered{}{\vspace{2ex}}}{}

\etocsetstyle{authors}{}{}{\etocname\par\vspace{1ex}}{\vspace{2ex}}

\etocsetstyle{section}{}{}{\makebox[0pt][r]{\etocnumber\hspace{\tocsep}}%
                           \etocname\kern1em\etocpage\par}{}

\etocsettocstyle {\noindent\sffamily{\LARGE \contentsname}\par
                  \thispagestyle{empty}%
                  \noindent\rule{\dimexpr\tocleft-\tocsep}{1pt}\par\vspace{3ex}%
                  \leftskip\tocleft\parindent0pt\def\TEMP{0}}{}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preface}

\mainmatter

\chapter*{A Few Words About Systems Engineering}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{A Few Words About Systems Engineering}

\part{Systems Engineering Practice}

\chapter{Methodology for an integrated Definition of a System and its
  Subsystems: The Case-Study of an Airplane and its Subsystems}

\authorstotoc{Sergio Chiesa, Marco Fioriti and Nicole Viola}

\section{This is a section}

\section{This is another section}

\chapter{Complex-Systems Design Methodology for Systems-Engineering
  Collaborative Environment}

\authorstotoc{Guido Ridolfi, Erwin Mooij and Sabrina Corpino}

\section{Another section}

\section{One more section}

\chapter*{A Few Words About Systems Engineering}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{A Few Words About Systems Engineering}

\section*{An unnumbered section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{An unnumbered section}

\end{document}
```

---

Earlier code, for the TOC without sections:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsetlevel{authors}{1}
\etocsetlevel{section}{2}
\etocsettocdepth{authors}
\newcommand{\authorstotoc}[1]{\etoctoccontentsline{authors}{#1}}

\newlength{\tocleft}
\setlength{\tocleft}{3cm}

\newlength{\tocsep}
\setlength{\tocsep}{2em}


\etocsetstyle{part}{}{}{{\bfseries\makebox[0pt][r]
                              {Part \etocnumber\hspace{\tocsep}}%
                     \etocname\quad\etocpage\par}\vspace{3ex}}{}

% to avoid possible line breaks between chapter (or part) name and page number     
% replace \quad by \kern1em\relax

\etocsetstyle{chapter}{}{}{\etocifnumbered
                             {\makebox[0pt][r]
                               {Chapter \etocnumber\hspace{\tocsep}}}
                             {\ifcase\TEMP
                              \def\TEMP{1}\or\def\TEMP{2}%
                              \makebox[0pt][r]
                                  {\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\tocleft-\tocsep\relax}
                                   {\raggedleft Introductory\\ \strut Chapter}%
                                   \hspace{\tocsep}}\fi
                              }\textbf{\etocname\quad\etocpage}\par
                             \etocifnumbered{}{\vspace{2ex}}}{}

\etocsetstyle{authors}{}{}{\etocname\par\vspace{2ex}}{}

\etocsettocstyle {\noindent\sffamily{\LARGE \contentsname}\par
                  \thispagestyle{empty}%
                  \noindent\rule{\dimexpr\tocleft-\tocsep}{1pt}\par\vspace{3ex}%
                  \leftskip\tocleft\parindent0pt\def\TEMP{0}}{}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preface}

\mainmatter

\chapter*{A Few Words About Systems Engineering}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{A Few Words About Systems Engineering}

\part{Systems Engineering Practice}

\chapter{Methodology for an integrated Definition of a System and its
  Subsystems: The Case-Study of an Airplane and its Subsystems}

\authorstotoc{Sergio Chiesa, Marco Fioriti and Nicole Viola}

\chapter{Complex-Systems Design Methodology for Systems-Engineering
  Collaborative Environment}

\authorstotoc{Guido Ridolfi, Erwin Mooij and Sabrina Corpino}

\end{document}
```

Comment: to avoid possible line breaks between chapter name and page number replace `\quad` by `\kern1em\relax`.

Comment: @ jfbu How can I use `\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}` with your code?

Comment: @minthao_2011 I don't know vietnamese, but I should have used `\chaptername\ ` and `\partname\ ` rather than `Chapter` and `Part`. There remains to translate `Introductory` in the code (and I don't know if it then should come before or after the translated `Chapter`).

Comment: Wow, thanks. The simplicity of this solution is amazing. Do you have any idea how we could add sections to the TOC, by removing the authors?

Comment: @Ingo see update. Oh sorry, did you really want the authors removed? I have kept them and added sections.

Comment: Why not both! This is a fantastic solution. I can always leave the authors away.

Comment: PS I will give you a bounty in 23 hours. Well deserved

Comment: @Ingo very generous of yours! if you don't want nor need the authors, then you can supress all `\etocsetlevel` lines, just maintain `\etocsettocdepth{section}`. However, replace then the first `{}` in `\etocsetstyle{section}` by `{\vspace{1ex}}` and the last `{}` by `{\vspace{2ex}}`. After modifying the source, suppress `.aux` et `.toc` file before recompiling. And comment out or suppress all `\authorstotoc` lines.

Answer (score 9):

This is not an answer to “how to reproduce”, but could give you some notion about how to start. Look at the TOC of my [note on functional analysis](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~hanche/notes/fnal/fnal.pdf). It is not what you're after, but I think you'll agree it is nonstandard.

Here is some (most?) of the code implementing this, from a local class file:

```
\renewcommand\l@chapter[2]
  {\vrule width0pt height 16pt depth 4pt
   \normalfont\bfseries#1&\normalfont\bfseries#2\cr}
\renewcommand\l@section[2]{\small#1&\small#2\cr}

\renewcommand\tableofcontents{\par
  \bigskip
  \begingroup\centering
  \renewcommand\numberline[1]{Chapter ##1:\enspace}
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\baselineskip10pt
    \halign{\hfil##\quad$\cdot$&\quad##\hfil\cr
      \@input{\jobname.toc}}}
  \par\endgroup
  \newwrite\tf@toc
  \immediate\openout\tf@toc\jobname.toc}
```

A bit of explanation: Here are the first two lines from the `.toc` file:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Transfinite induction}{3}
\contentsline {section}{Wellordering}{3}
```

These expand into (assuming `@` is a letter)

```
\l@chapter{\numberline {1}Transfinite induction}{3}
\l@section{Wellordering}{3}
```

so `\l@chapter` and friends are the macros that need tweaking. Here, I made them produce output suitable for going into an `\halign` construct.

From these ideas, you may be able to produce something similar for your preferred layout. You will need to alter the `\chapter` command to also include author information in its call to `\addcontentsline`, and of course `\l@chapter` must be able to pick this information out of its two argument. Easy solution: Let the first argument have the form `{chapter title}{author info}` and use an auxiliary macro to tease the bits apart.

**Disclaimer:** It's years since I wrote that code. My understanding of it has very likely deteriorated.